# Convert Pandas Series to DateTime in a DataFrame

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame as below

```
        ReviewID       ID      Type               TimeReviewed
205     76032930  51936827  ReportID 2015-01-15 00:05:27.513000
232     76032930  51936854  ReportID 2015-01-15 00:06:46.703000
233     76032930  51936855  ReportID 2015-01-15 00:06:56.707000
413     76032930  51937035  ReportID 2015-01-15 00:14:24.957000
565     76032930  51937188  ReportID 2015-01-15 00:23:07.220000

>>> type(df)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

TimeReviewed is a series type

```
>>> type(df.TimeReviewed)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I've tried below, but it still doesn't change the Series type

```
import pandas as pd
review = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(df.TimeReviewed))
>>> type(review)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

How can I change the df.TimeReviewed to DateTime type and pull out year, month, day, hour, min, sec separately? 
I'm kinda new to python, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can't: `DataFrame` columns are `Series`, by definition.  That said, if you make the `dtype` (the type of all the elements) datetime-like, then you can access the quantities you want via the `.dt` accessor ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#dt-accessor)):

```
>>> df["TimeReviewed"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TimeReviewed"])
>>> df["TimeReviewed"]
205  76032930   2015-01-24 00:05:27.513000
232  76032930   2015-01-24 00:06:46.703000
233  76032930   2015-01-24 00:06:56.707000
413  76032930   2015-01-24 00:14:24.957000
565  76032930   2015-01-24 00:23:07.220000
Name: TimeReviewed, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> df["TimeReviewed"].dt
<pandas.tseries.common.DatetimeProperties object at 0xb10da60c>
>>> df["TimeReviewed"].dt.year
205  76032930    2015
232  76032930    2015
233  76032930    2015
413  76032930    2015
565  76032930    2015
dtype: int64
>>> df["TimeReviewed"].dt.month
205  76032930    1
232  76032930    1
233  76032930    1
413  76032930    1
565  76032930    1
dtype: int64
>>> df["TimeReviewed"].dt.minute
205  76032930     5
232  76032930     6
233  76032930     6
413  76032930    14
565  76032930    23
dtype: int64
```

---

If you're stuck using an older version of `pandas`, you can always access the various elements manually (again, after converting it to a datetime-dtyped Series).  It'll be slower, but sometimes that isn't an issue:

```
>>> df["TimeReviewed"].apply(lambda x: x.year)
205  76032930    2015
232  76032930    2015
233  76032930    2015
413  76032930    2015
565  76032930    2015
Name: TimeReviewed, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I couldn't use `.dt` it give me an error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'dt'`

Comment: @user3596895: you're probably using an older version of pandas.  What does `print(pd.version.version)` give?

Comment: @user3596895: time to upgrade, then. :-)

Comment: I see, I'm using visual studio python tool import pandas, will look up how to update my pandas version, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
df=pd.read_csv("filename.csv" , parse_dates=["<column name>"])

type(df.<column name>)
```

example: if you want to convert day which is initially a string to a Timestamp in Pandas

```
df=pd.read_csv("weather_data2.csv" , parse_dates=["day"])

type(df.day)
```

The output will be `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`

Comment: Hi, what if I have to parse the dates for two columns? Nothing I tried seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

Some handy script:

```
hour = df['assess_time'].dt.hour.values[0]
```