# Conversion of Strings to Datetime Pandas - tried everything

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I know there are a lot of similar questions but I am pretty sure I have tried everything I found

Data:

```
    TimeStamp
    10:34:30
    10:35:30
    10:36:30
    10:37:30
```

I have two different .csv files and I am trying to compare the times from the two in order determine further action.

I want to use `.dt.hour` or `.dt.min` to compare the times. Here's what I tried:
The type always remains str or float and the `.dt.hour` or .`dt.min` does not work

```
    def csv_to_df(path, filename):
        dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S')
        df = pd.read_csv(path + filename, skipinitialspace = True, parse_dates = True, date_parser = dateparse)
        return df
```

I also tried using pd.to_datetime later for conversion. That didn't work either.

```
    df_sr4500.TimeStamp=pd.to_datetime(df_sr4500.TimeStamp).dt.time
    print(df_sr4500.TimeStamp[1].dt.hour)

    ERROR: AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

Comment: have you tried `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: @MattR yes in the form: df['Mycol'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Mycol'], format='%\H:%M:%S')

Comment: and what was that result? That may help us find out the issue.

Comment: it gives me errors when I try to use df.iloc[0,0].dt.hour;  it tells me that type 'str' doesn't have an attribute '.dt'

Comment: Please post that in the original question for others to see. It's hard to understand comment code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Pandas Series to DateTime in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133018/convert-pandas-series-to-datetime-in-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.TimeStamp=pd.to_datetime(df.TimeStamp).dt.time

df.TimeStamp[1]
Out[115]: datetime.time(10, 35, 30)

df.TimeStamp[1].hour

Out[119]: 10
```

In case you need convert new column hour

```
df.TimeStamp.apply(lambda x : x.hour)
Out[122]: 
0    10
1    10
2    10
3    10
Name: TimeStamp, dtype: int64
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'dt'

Comment: Is your original data type ==string ?

Comment: @Brain_overflowed that is working on my side , and use your original df to test it

Comment: @Brain_overflowed after you figure out how to solve your problem , I will delete the answer.

Comment: @Brain_overflowed yw

Answer (score 0):

`df.TimeStamp = pd.to_datetime(df_sr4500.TimeStamp)` is sufficient.

To get the hour or the minute from this column you need the following:

```
[i.hour for i in df.TimeStamp]
```

Note: `.dt` access an individual item but you are trying to access it using an entire series.