# python how to convert one column in dataframe to date tye and plot

Tags: python, date, dataframe, plot

I have one dataframe  df as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [20121231,20130102, 20130105, 20130106, 20130107, 20130108],'price': [25, 163, 235, 36, 40, 82]})
```

How to make `df['date']` as `date type` and make `'price'` as `y-label` and `'date'` as `x-label`?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `format`, check [`http://strftime.org/`](http://strftime.org/):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
print (df)
        date  price
0 2012-12-31     25
1 2013-01-02    163
2 2013-01-05    235
3 2013-01-06     36
4 2013-01-07     40
5 2013-01-08     82
```

And then [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df.plot(x='date', y='price')
```

Comment: Great.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [20121231,20130102, 20130105, 20130106, 20130107, 
                            20130108],'price': [25, 163, 235, 36, 40, 82]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')

df.plot(x='date', y='price')
```

Answer (score 1):

With `pandas` you can directly convert the *date* column to `datetime` type. And then you can plot with `matplotlib`. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12945971/5535114) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28133042/5535114).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as dates

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'date': [20121231, 20130102, 20130105, 20130106, 20130107, 20130108],
    'price': [25, 163, 235, 36, 40, 82]
})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Date plot with matplotlib
ax.plot_date(
    pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y%m%d"),
    df["price"],
    'v-'
)

# Days and months and the horizontal locators
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.DayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d\n%a'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('\n\n\n%b\n%Y'))

ax.xaxis.grid(True, which="minor")
ax.yaxis.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]