# Get day from pandas datetime variable

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a pandas datetime object that I want to extract the day, month, year out of it.

```
print(data)
1   2012-09-21
2   2012-09-28
3   2012-10-05
4   2012-10-12
5   2012-10-19
6   2012-10-26
Name: Date, Length: 143, dtype: datetime64[ns]

data.day
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'day'
```

Any help on this one?
Thanks

Comment: Use `data.dt.day`

Comment: @jezrael actually works.. Whats the dt?

Comment: It is accestor for convert columns, Series to datetimelike functions - [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.html?highlight=dt#pandas.Series.dt)

Comment: Thats nice, would you post the answer or it's not worth it?

Comment: I found better answer, so because already answering, rather not.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28133018)

Comment: I guess.. Btw congrats for your #2 of the year, such an amazing accomplishment.

Comment: Thank you very much! ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181062/discussion-between-miguel-santos-and-jezrael).