# Extract all time elements from a column

Tags: python, pandas, eda

I have a dataset with a column named ['STime'] that I want to use to create many columns containing each time element (Year, Month, day, etc). The column values have this format 2016-04-16 10:12:41. I tried creating a year column separately using:

```
 data['SYear'] = data['SDate'].year
```

It gave me an error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year'

How can I solve this?

Comment: `data['SDate'].dt.year`?

Comment: I think it might be answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/28133018/2894909

Comment: yes this worked! I used it on separate rows without dt and it worked. not sure why it doesnt work when I try to apply it to the whole column

Answer (score 1):

`data['SDate']` is a series, a series has no attribute `year`. However, you can map a series through a function and save the result in a new column, like:

```
data['SYear'] = data['SDate'].map(lambda d: d.year)
```

This will `map` each value of the column `SDate` through the lambda function and generate a new Pandas series, which will be saved in the new column.