# python convert datetime with time zone to date

Tags: python, pandas, string, date, datetime

I am trying to convert my datetime column to date.

Here is how my date value looks:

```
2023-06-25T00:00:00.000Z
```

and I want to convert it to

```
2023-06-25
```

This command;

```
df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

does not work.
The error message that I am getting states `"Attribute Error: Can only use .dt accessor with datetime like values"`.

Also, when I run

```
df.info
```

it is stating that date is an object.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: What does your console look like when you print `df["date"]`?

Comment: If it's saying the dtype is object, there's probably some non-datetime values in the column.

Comment: You should first try to convert the column to datetime, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133018/convert-pandas-series-to-datetime-in-a-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# Assuming 'df' is your DataFrame
# Convert 'date' column to datetime format
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Extract only the date part and overwrite the 'date' column
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.date

# Now, 'date' column will contain only the date (yyyy-mm-dd)
print(df['date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

To change from object to datetime64 you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'date': ['2023-06-25T00:00:00.000Z']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(df)
```

And if you do df.info() it will say datetime64, not object